# Remove QTKit dependency

Tags: ffmpeg, dependencies, deprecated, qtkit

I want to submint an application using [FFMPEG](http://ffmpeg.org/) to the *Mac App Store* but I get rejected because *libavcodec* links against the deprecated *QTKit* framework:

```
Deprecated API Usage - Apple no longer accepts submissions of apps that use QuickTime APIs.
```

I installed *ffmpeg* using `brew install ffmpeg`. How can I remove this dependency?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could recompile FFmpeg from sources disabling the QTKit by adding `--disable-indev=qtkit` to the `./configure` call. Since you have not stated what exactly are you using FFmpeg for this may not solve the issue - if you use a component that directly relies on QTKit then you will not have that functionality if FFmpeg is compiled without QTKit.

Comment: Is it possible to do it using `brew`? Do I have to modify the formula? https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/ffmpeg.rb

Comment: I'm not very familiar with homebrew, but looking at the formula, you could try to add the --disable-indev=qtkit line to the args block on line 67 and see if that helps.

Comment: I will try to add an option instead and I'll send a PR.

Comment: This should do the trick: https://github.com/MartinDelille/homebrew/commit/7f8f42ef4f65088bfcd18d570ccce8b44434c7b0

Comment: Well, you'll see if it does when you have built it, but looks fine.